# accentbx vs \parbox, or \' vs \"

Tags: accents

Minion Pro font does not have `^^^^0301` accent working. So to get accents above cyrillic letters I use `accentbx` package. But unfortunately the accent gets broken if included in a `\parbox{}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro} 
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{russian} 
\usepackage{accentbx}
\def\'#1{\upaccent{\aboxshift[.9ex]{^^^^00b4}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
акц\'ент
\textit{акц\'ент}
\textbf{акц\'ент}
{\uppercase{
акц\'ент
\textit{акц\'ент}
\textbf{акц\'ент}}}

\parbox{3 cm}{акц\'ент е^^^^00b4 \upaccent{\aboxshift[.9ex]{^^^^00b4}}{е}}
\end{document}
```

[image: accentbx killed by parbox]

How can I fix it?

UPDATE:
It's weird, but

```
\def\"#1{\upaccent{\aboxshift[.9ex]{^^^^00b4}}{#1}}
...
\parbox{3 cm}{акц\"ент}
```

works OK.

Why is there such a difference between \' and \"?

Comment: thanks for the tick. I'll leave my answer as it explains why `\'` and `\"` are different, but you should accept Ulrike's answer:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `\def` to define your accent command – this will break the definitions of other encodings. Also you shouldn't load fontenc after fontspec as this changes the default encoding. I would redefine `\'` like this (I don't have your accentbx package, so I'm using `\fbox` as example):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

\DeclareTextCommand{\'}{\UTFencname}[1]
   {\fbox{#1}}

\begin{document}


акц\'ент
\textit{акц\'ент}
\textbf{акц\'ент}
{\uppercase{
акц\'ент
\textit{акц\'ент}
\textbf{акц\'ент}}}

\parbox{3 cm}{акц\'ент}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I left a comment on the question suggesting the OP accept this one rather than the other answer someone left...

Answer (score 4):

Due to it being overloaded by the tabbing environment latex has a saved version of `\'` known as `\@acci` that is restored in parboxes and similar places.

So after redefining the accent redefine the saved copy

```
\makeatletter
\let\@acci\'
\makeatother
```